# Existence of normal structure in strictly convex Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does there exists a strictly convex Banach space which is not uniformly convex and has normal structure ?

Comment: You may consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. This is Theorem 3.1 in

> L. P. Belluce, W. A. Kirk, and E. F. Steiner, [Normal structure in Banach spaces](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102985731). *Pacific J. Math.* **6**, (1968), 433-440.